# $U \times V$ is open in the product metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following statement:
"Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces and that $U \subseteq X$ and $V \subseteq Y$ are open. Show that $U \times V \subseteq X \times Y$ is open in the product metric on $X \times Y$."
This is what I have so far:
"Let $U \subseteq X$ and $V \subseteq Y$ be open in $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, respectively.
Then by definition, for all $u \in U$, there exists some $\epsilon_1>0$ such that $B_{d_X}(u,\epsilon_1) \subseteq U$ and for all $v \in V$, there exists some $\epsilon_2>0$ such that $B_{d_Y}(v,\epsilon_2) \subseteq V$.
Let $\epsilon=\max{\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}}$.
Additionally, let $(u_o,v_o) \in U \times V$."
I'm confused as to where to go from here. Any tips?

Comment: What is the product metric?

Comment: We're defining the product metric to be $d_{X \times Y}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\max{\{d_X(x_1,x_2),d_Y(y_1,y_2)\}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u\in U$ and $v\in V$, take $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{d_X}(u,\varepsilon)\subset U$ and that $B_{d_Y}(u,\varepsilon)\subset V$. Then$$B_{d_{X\times Y}}\bigl((u,v),\varepsilon\bigr)\subset U\times V.$$That's so because, if $(x,t)\in X\times Y$,\begin{align}(x,y)\in B_{d_{X\times Y}}\bigl((u,v),\varepsilon\bigr)&\iff\max\{d_X(x,u),d_Y(y,v)\}<\varepsilon\\&\iff d_X(x,u),d_Y(y,v)<\varepsilon\\&\implies x\in U\wedge y\in V.\end{align}

Comment: Would that be all that I need to add?

Comment: @bzoll213 I've edited my answer, adding a few lines. Yes, it is all you need to do.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Should I keep what I have and just add this to it or revise my proof completely to something akin to what you wrote?

Comment: If you start like that, then the $\varepsilon$ that you should take is $\min\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should start the prof by taking an arbitrary element $(u_0,v_0)$ of $U \times V$. We then get $u_o \in U$ and $v_0 \in V$. So there exist $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 >0$ such that $B_{d_X}(u_0,\epsilon_1) \subseteq U$ and $B_{d_Y}(v_0,\epsilon_2) \subseteq V$. Let $\epsilon=\min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$. Can you check now that this $\epsilon$ works?